# "Unable to start correctly (0xc0150002)" error on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013, openssl

I am unable to launch my application on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64. It was built via Visual Studio 2013 (toolset -- v120_xp, static linkage with CRT). On other systems (for example, Windows 8 x64 and Windows 7 x64) application works as expected, while on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 it gives me the following error:

[image]

When I try to run this application via WinDbg it shows this error right after the following line:

> ModLoad: 00000000`007b0000 00000000`0094a000
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\app\LIBEAY32.dll

I've tried to download x64 OpenSSL binaries and replace the "libeay32.dll" and "ssleay32.dll" files in the application's directory, but it gives me the same error.

Yes, there are a lot of questions about similar errors, but unfortunately I didn't find any answer for my case.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the Windows event log?

Comment: Have you tried using the dependancy walker (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/256872) to spot any issues on both systems?

Comment: This might help:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2008/08/07/part-2-troubleshooting-vc-side-by-side-problems.aspx